# Transcoder API not working via Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-storage, google-cloud-transcoder

I use Firebase in my Unity App. User's can upload videos to Firebase Storage (it's working good) and then I make trigger in Firebase Cloud Functions to transcode video (via Google Cloud Platform Transcoder API). This is not work, and I don't know why.

Google Cloud console cloud functions error:
"Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: Invalid resource field value in the request."

Here is my code:

```
  const functions = require("firebase-functions");
    const admin = require("firebase-admin");
    admin.initializeApp();
    
    const db = admin.firestore();
    const { TranscoderServiceClient } = require('@google-cloud/video-transcoder');
    const { Storage } = require('@google-cloud/storage');
    const storage = new Storage();
    
//other functions..
//

    exports.transcodeVideo = functions.storage.object().onFinalize(async (object) => {
      try {
        const fileBucket = object.bucket;
        const filePath = object.name;
        const videoPath = `gs://${fileBucket}/${filePath}`;
    
        // Only if in videos/..
        if (!filePath.startsWith('videos/')) {
          console.log('Nem történt videó feltöltés az videos/ könyvtárba. A Cloud Function nem fut le.');
          return null;
        }
    
        console.log(`1. Transcode folyamat elindítva a videóhoz: ${videoPath}`);
    //videoPath is good!
    
        // A Google Cloud Transcoder API kliens inicializálása
        const transcoderClient = new TranscoderServiceClient();
    
        // Az új transcode elrendezés konfigurálása
        const jobTemplate = {
          jobConfig: {
            inputUri: videoPath,
            outputUri: 'gs://MY_APP.appspot.com/output/optimised.mp4', // THIS IS ONLY TEST NAME. MY_APP is my app.
            elementaryStreams: [
              {
                key: 'video_stream',
                videoStream: {
                  codec: 'h264',
                  heightPixels: 360, // Válaszd meg a kívánt alacsony SD felbontást
                  widthPixels: 640, // Válaszd meg a kívánt alacsony SD felbontást
                  bitrateBps: 1000000 // Válaszd meg a kívánt alacsony SD bitrátát
                }
              }
            ],
            muxStreams: [
              {
                key: 'sd_mux_stream',
                container: 'mp4'
              }
            ]
          }
        };
    
        console.log(`start transcode`); //After this get error in my console
        
        // Az új transcode elrendezés létrehozása és futtatása
        const [response] = await transcoderClient.createJob({
          job: jobTemplate
        });
    
        console.log(`Transcode folyamat elindítva a videóhoz: ${videoPath}`);
        //I don't see this in console, error before this.
    
        // A nem optimalizált videó törlése
        await storage.bucket(fileBucket).file(filePath).delete();
        console.log(`Nem optimalizált videó törölve: ${videoPath}`);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Hiba történt a transcode folyamat során:', error);
      }
    });
```

I don't know what is the problem.. Other functions work good. Cloud storage have service-account permission. I use "firebase deploy" command because my project base in firebase. I see in stack overflow maybe need other permission for "gcloud deploy...", but I use firebase. Maybe need to install gcloud too? Firebase storage = cloud storage, I think it is need work, but I don't know why get always this error.

Please help.
Thanks,
Adrian

Answer (score 0):

I'm not versed in Google Cloud Transponder but looking at the [Transcoder API Documentation](https://Transcoder%20API%20Documentation) and at an official [sample](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-node/blob/main/packages/google-cloud-video-transcoder/samples/generated/v1/transcoder_service.create_job.js) you need to pass to the `createJob()` method an object having these two properties:

```
{
  parent,
  job,
}
```

`parent` is a string representing the parent location to create and process the job (Format: `projects/{project}/locations/{location}`). It is unclear to me if it is required or not, the sample and the doc are not aligned on this aspect.

`job` is a compounded Object of type [`IJobTemplate`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/transcoder/latest/google.cloud.video.transcoder.v1.IJobTemplate.html) with the following properties: `name`, `config` and `labels`. In turn, `config` is a compounded Object of type [`IJobConfig`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/transcoder/latest/google.cloud.video.transcoder.v1.IJobConfig.html).

So you need to do something along the following lines (untested):

```
const request = {
      parent: "....",
      job: {
        name: "...",
        config: {
            inputUri: videoPath,
            outputUri: 'gs://MY_APP.appspot.com/output/optimised.mp4',
            ...
        }
      }
   };

// ...

const [response] = await transcoderClient.createJob(request);
// ...
```

*(Hoping it helps you as this answer is strictly based on the documentation)*

Comment: Hey @AdriánVarga did you have the time to look at the proposed solution?